# Game scene broken in android build but not editor?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Hey so I am making a VR game and recently the scene out of nowhere just broke in the ingame build. I have looked in editor and test played in editor but it is normal in editor.

The weird thing is this seems to happen in every scene except a couple.

In Editor:

[image]

Ingame:

[Video link if it doesn't work tell me!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1BVw8ERDUq4POGUZtuJ_yPFytaZn_iw/view?usp=sharing)

I am trying to build the lighting to see if that helps but idk if it will just seeing if anyone knows what I could do.

Graphics API:

[image]

Comment: Which graphics API is set in Player Settings?
And
Have you tried different devices?

Comment: Hey I have tried it on the different devices my game is available on. My friend tried it on his, I tried it on mine, and other friend we all have the same issue.

I will add my graphics API settings screenshot to the post above

Comment: Hey I have found the issue only happens usually when switching scenes.

Comment: Switch to gamma for color space and check result.

Comment: Sadly the platfrom I am building for does not support gamma color space any other ideas as to what I could do